# Most efficient way to query a large amount of data using C# and Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql

I have a web application (ASP.NET 4.0 in c#) and I am building a pseudo Adhoc component.  This component allows the user to select from a list of predetermined categories (Car Make, Care Model, Car Accessories, etc).  The user can select as many categories as they wish and then they press a "Filter" button which will take the categories that are selected and send them to a new form with the options of each category.  Each category can have multiple options.

Example:
User selects Car Color, Car accessories.

Filter page shows a form with a drop down pre-populated with colors for Car Color.  Form shows a check box for Satellite Radio, another check box for Leather Interior, etc.  All of these values are predefined.  Once a user specifies all of the items they can filter upon, I am using Linq to query the database.  As it is now, the Linq query is against a View that currently holds 14 Left Outer Joins and, if not filtered at all, returns over 30,000 rows.

I am using dynamic linq to query to database link so:

```
var data = CMS.Model.Adhoc.GetData().AsQueryable(); //must be AsQueryablefor Dynamic Linq to function

    public static List<ViewADHOCContractInfo> GetData()
    {
        PortalDataContext db = new PortalDataContext(AuthenticatedUser.ConnectionString);

        return db.ViewADHOCInfos.Select(x=>x).Distinct().ToList();
    }
```

NOTE that GetData() is returning all rows and all columns of the result set, which I do not think is the most efficient way to do this, more on that at the bottom.

From there I am performing a FOREACH statement on the filters that were sent in, and minimizing the result set on each iteration like so (abbreviated):

```
foreach (Filters filter in filters.OrderBy(x=>x.strOrderNumber))
        {
            SanatizeFilter(filter.strFilter,filter);
            if (filter.strValue != string.Empty && filter.strValue != null)
            {
                if (filter.strOperator == "Contains")
                {
                    data = data.Where(filter.strFilter + "!= NULL and " + filter.strFilter + ".Contains(@0)", filter.strValue).
                        Select(x => x).ToList().AsQueryable();
                }
                else
                {
                    data = data.Where(filter.strFilter + FormatOperator(filter.strOperator) + "@0", filter.strValue).
                        Select(x => x).ToList().AsQueryable();


                }
            }
        }
```

All of this works fine, however it is slow.  My first question is, how can I use Linq to cut this down a bit.  I have tried a few ways to pull only the data that comes from the filter into the variable "data" as a way to pre-populate, however I can't get that to work with the .AsQueryable().  I would like to be able to get the column identifiers from the filter objects and select only those from the database so that I don't have to deal with all of the overhead, but I can't find a solution that will allow me to do this, any ideas?

Second Question is right now this is all in a view in the database, would it be faster/more efficient to move it to a function or a stored procedure?  Can Linq interact with a stored procedure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why `ToList()`? If you just enumerate your data why you do not simply return `IEnumerable<T>`? You'll let the implementation free to fetch all data in one shot or, when it can be avoided, to fetch only what needed (and as needed). 2nd: yes, LINQ (LINQ to SQL or EF) can call a stored procedure.

Comment: All of the `ToList`s that you're adding are preventing your queries from being executed at the database.  Anything you do after a `ToList` call will be done in C#.  If you really need a list at some point, then wait until the end to call it.

Comment: If your table gets bigger than 56,000 rows, you're going to regret not letting the DB engine filter the data before you do a `ToList`..

Comment: @NWest it will get much larger than that, what do you mean by letting the DBN engine filter?  How can I do that with Linq?

Comment: Do your filtering in the db.ViewADHOCInfos.Select call, using the LINQ [`WHERE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311043.aspx) clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question can be split in two parts:

1) Is my linq-2-sql approach good

2) Is my database approach good

The first part can be solved by profiling your SQL that is send to the database. This will show you what query/queries are actually executed. As you can see in the comments, by using ToList() early in your approach, this might be far from optimal. Databases are very good in filtering and handling large sets of data. So let them do what they are best at!

Now the second part of your question is about the view. Would it be faster to use a stored procedur etc? To answer a part of your question: yes, Linq-2-sql can use a stored procedure as well. But if you are using the stored to procedure to retrieve too much data, it will still be slow. This is the DBA-part of the story. Perhaps a few indexes on the base tables will be sufficient. Another approach can be to add a clustered index to your view which in turn materializes it.

I would advise you first to deal with the linq-2-sql part: make sure that the sql that is actually excecuted is **set-based** and all of your filtering is being done in the database. If it is still too slow, move on to the database layer and see what you can improve there.